# SQLAlchemy: replacing object with a new one, following defaults

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to create a new instance of an SQLAlchemy object, so that fields are filled with default values, but I want to commit that to the database generating an `UPDATE` to a row that already exists with the same primary key, effectively resetting it to the default values. Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do that and failed, because SQLAlchemy session tracks state of objects. So there is no easy way to make session to track new object as persistent one.

But you want to reset object to default, do you? There is a simple way to do that:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class Base(object):

    def reset(self):
        for name, column in self.__class__.__table__.columns.items():
            if column.default is not None:
                setattr(self, name, column.default.execute())

Base = declarative_base(bind=engine, cls=Base)
```

This adds `reset` method to all your model classes.

Here is the complete working example to fiddle with:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime


from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import functions


here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///%s/db.sqlite' % here, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class Base(object):

    def reset(self):
        for name, column in self.__class__.__table__.columns.items():
            if column.default is not None:
                setattr(self, name, column.default.execute())

Base = declarative_base(bind=engine, cls=Base)


class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'things'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String(255), default='default')
    ts1 = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    ts2 = Column(DateTime, default=functions.now())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Thing(id={0.id!r}, value={0.value!r}, ' \
               'ts1={0.ts1!r}, ts2={0.ts2!r})>'.format(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.drop_all()
    Base.metadata.create_all()

    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("Create a new thing")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    session = Session()
    thing = Thing(
        value='some value',
        ts1=datetime(2014, 1, 1),
        ts2=datetime(2014, 2, 2),
    )
    session.add(thing)
    session.commit()
    session.close()

    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("Quering it from DB")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    session = Session()
    thing = session.query(Thing).filter(Thing.id == 1).one()
    print(thing)
    session.close()

    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("Reset it to default")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    session = Session()
    thing = session.query(Thing).filter(Thing.id == 1).one()
    thing.reset()
    session.commit()
    session.close()

    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("Quering it from DB")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    session = Session()
    thing = session.query(Thing).filter(Thing.id == 1).one()
    print(thing)
    session.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the reset approach doesn't solve the problem for me. Yes, I want to reset to defaults, but it's really important that I do that by creating a new instance with the defaults, and the choice between inserting a new one or updating an existent is dealt with.

Comment: @PedroWerneck In that case, try to hack around [object state](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#getting-the-current-state-of-an-object). Public interface is read only, but it can be modified. IMHO, it is dirty unstable solution (nobody gives guarantee it will work in future versions of SQLAlchemy). However, it might be useful for you.

Comment: I'd be glad if you could edit your answer and elaborate on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any simple way to do that?

Upon further consideration, not really. The cleanest way will be to define your defaults in `__init__`. The constructor is never called when fetching objects from the DB, so it's perfectly safe. You can also use backend functions such as `current_timestamp()`.

```
class MyObject(Base):
    id = Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    column1 = Column(sa.String)
    column2 = Column(sa.Integer)
    columnN = Column(sa.String)
    updated = Column(sa.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('column1', 'default value')
        kwargs.setdefault('column2', 123)
        kwargs.setdefault('columnN', None)
        kwargs.setdefault('updated', sa.func.current_timestamp())
        super(MyObject, self).__init__(**kwargs)

default_obj = MyObject()
default_obj.id = old_id
session.merge(default_obj)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Are you sure? That doesn't work at all for me. Actually, after the commit I have the original object unchanged, as if nothing happened.

Comment: Actually I just noticed my test code was using __init__ to set some values, which appears to make a big difference. Merge works fine for edited values but doesn't trigger default(). You could always just create a new instance, copy the key, delete the old and add the new.